# use replace() but I don't need origin string

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function with `replace()`

```
function myfunc(hex){
  const value = hex
    .replace(/^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i,(m, r, g, b) => { return "#"+r+r+g+g+b+b });
}
```

```
23:51 'm' is declared but its value is never read.
    21 | function myfunc(hex){
    22 |   const value = hex
  > 23 |     .replace(/^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i, (m, r, g, b) => {
```

I don't need `m` but I want to throw it.

I know it caused `jsconfig`, but I can't touch it.

```
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
```

Comment: They may have a "discard" variable. Have you tried an underscore in place of `n`?

Comment: How about `{ m; return ... `

Comment: you might be able to use `_`, something like: `(_, r, g, b) => {`

Comment: `(m, r, g, b) => { return "#"+r+r+g+g+b+b }` can be written without the `return` or the braces.